# System.XML.XMLException Root Element is Missing in VB.NET

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I'm trying to read a `XML` document from a URL and displaying a specific attribute in the Console.

My XML Document Downloaded Looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Shift_JIS" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
<ReportTime>2021/04/04 14:38:56</ReportTime>
<WeatherReport Id="LNAS441" Time="2021/04/05 14:36:00" Prediction="sunny">
<DetailOneHR>Partly Sunny</DetailOneHR>
<DetailTwoHR>Sunny</DetailTwoHR>
<DetailThreeHR>data/JS00clA0210405143615_20210405143856.jpg</DetailThreeHR>
<Relative>
<Group Report="Sunny">
<Area Name="Northwest off Region 12" />
</Group>
</Relative>
</WeatherReport>
</Root>
```

I've written some code in an attempt to get the contents of `ID` (LNAS441) in the `WeatherReport` section. However, when I run the code, I get the error of:

> System.Xml.XmlException: 'Root element is missing.'

Here is the code:

```
Dim address As String = "https://example.com/WeatherDecodeAPI/XML/current.xml"
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT_JIS")
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT_JIS"))

Dim docxElement As XElement = XElement.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd())

XMLID = docxElement.@Id 'Get the ID

Console.WriteLine(XMLID)
```

I'm not sure what is wrong in this code. The XML I'm using does seem to have a root element. How would I fix this?

Comment: You should be using XDocument.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd) (not XElement).  You probably do not need the WebClient.  Just use : XDocument.Load(URL)

Comment: Can you provide the URI that produced that XML.  The XML you posted is valid.

Comment: I saved this API request directly from the URL. @jdweng I tried writing this code, but it just writes nothing in the console for the ID: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/1r089Vqe). What is wrong in this?

Comment: XMLID = doc.Descendants("WeatherReport").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("Id").Value;

Comment: It works and finally prints out the ID. Thanks!